# whether given lattice is distributive or complemented or both?

Tags: lattice-orders

whether given lattice is distributive or complemented or both?

```
       a
      /|\
     / | \
    b  |  c
    |  d  |
    e  |  f
    \  | / 
     \ |/
       g
```

For a lattice to be distributive each element should have unique complement.
here d can have two b & c , hence it is not distributive. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  Another way to see this (which might be easier for more complicated lattices) is to note that the lattice has [$N_5$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:N5_1bax0.svg) and [$M_3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:M_3_mit_Beschriftung.svg) as sublattices.  A lattice is distributive iff it has no sublattice isomorphic to $N_5$ or $M_3$.  (A lattice is modular iff it has no sublattice $\cong N_5$.)